# Global Http Request exception handler using MooTools. How it will behavior when GET/POST is bypassed

Tags: javascript, mootools

How to write a global exception handler for HTTP Request in MooTools?
How it will behave when GET/POST is bypassing MooTools library, for example GET/POST is done by YUI datagrid.

Is it possible to write handler which will be called whenever Http Request exception occurred.Doesn't matter whether it is called using MooTools OR YUI.

Comment: if it works through the Request class, then yes, you can refactor the `onComplete` and `onFailure` to run custom code as they raise the events. The question is, is YUI reliant on the Request class or does it use their own. If the latter, then it's a moot point as you'd have to also refactor theirs. post again if you need help refactoring the Request class. In terms of architecture, I'd actually consider **extending** request into something like `Request.safe = new Class({ Extends: Request });` - though this won't cater for flavours like Request.HTML. It's a bad practice to change the default..

Comment: ... expected behavior of a framework class / function as it can make debugging difficult down the line when being looked by somebody familiar with the original code and not aware of your prototype changes. Hence my suggestion to extend into a new class instead, then it's clear to everyone.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, I don't want to extend class because, there are existing libraries, for example YUI grid I am using. so It is important that I attach handler at browser event or atleast one for mootools and another for YUI. But then it should capture any request exception done by MooTools or YUI.

Comment: I am thinking of doing Request.implement , but not sure how to implement is properly, so it calls current Mootools implementation and also calls new global handler if any.

Comment: use [Class.Refactor](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Class.Refactor) - which lets you use `this.previous()` to call the existing method and you can add logic after or before that.